# PHP Raspberry pi - str_repeat() has issues when string is > chr(127)

Tags: php

If I run the code below on my Fedora 17/19 servers it runs fine.
However when it's run on my RPi , the str_repeat only puts the
chr(250) in the first and last position and has (3) of another 
character between them.

Only values < 128 work ok.

is there a setting I need to fix on the RPi to allow str_repeat
or is there a bug in the php executable for the Rpi?

```
<?php

   $x=chr(250);
   $test="hello";
   echo $test."\n";
   $test=$test.str_repeat($x,5);
   echo $test."\n";

?>
```

Thanks
GG

Comment: What character is the 250?

Comment: I'd say it has something to do with different charactersets on both machines

Comment: This question isn't specific to the Raspberry Pi hardware - I've removed the tag.

Comment: I'm using not just 250, it's just a character that won't be used in the data - I'm using it as a delimiter - actually I'm using 3 for a 3 dimensional serialized array.

Comment: If i use a for loop with concatenation - the output is correct, it's only when I use the str_repeat function that the output is skewed, and only on the Rpi - which "should" be using the same charset as the two Fedora servers - as they are all using the default which for PHP4/5 should be UTF-8. I also hardcoded UTF-8 as well - and that did not solve the issue. I can always use the for loop for my purposes and all will be well - I'm just confused on why the intrinsic function fails?

Answer (score 0):

as  vrijdenker was eluding to it's probably just a matter of your terminal not being able to display those characters properly. (sorry i cant just add a comment because i don't have enough points here yet!)

Comment: If it were the terminal not being able to display I could see that - however, that shouldn't be an issue if i weren't using echo's, there should be no character set involved?